# "Rooms and Equipment" User Query

Tags: azure, powershell, exchange-server

I've been banging away at this problem here without any solid solution.  I'm attempting to pull all group data of a user from Azure/Exchange Online shared mailboxes,O365 Groups, Sharepoints, Rooms & Equipment/Resources.  The purpose is to them purge the user of all of the groups/distros.  I can successfully pull almost all of the users group information by using the first section of code below.  However I am struggling to all grab the Rooms and Equipment/Resources groups.  [Credit](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/09/find-all-office-365-groups-user-is-member-of-using-powershell.html#:%7E:text=Login%20to%20Microsoft%20365%20Admin,user%20is%20a%20member%20of.)

```
Import-Module AzureAd -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Parameters
$UserID = "user@contoso.com"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\GroupMemberships.csv"
 
Try {
    #Connect to Azure AD
    Connect-AzureAD -Credential (Get-Credential) | Out-Null
 
    #Get the User
    $User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserID
 
    #Get User's Group Memberships
    $Memberships = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $User.ObjectId | Where-object { $_.ObjectType -eq "Group" }
 
    #Export group memberships to a CSV
    $Memberships | Select DisplayName, Mail, ObjectId | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "`tError:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

And I'm able to query the list of Rooms and Equipment separately by using;

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox")' | Select Name,Alias
```

It seems like I would need to gather the list of "RoomMailbox" (AKA Rooms and Equipment mailboxes) and then filter through all of them to see if the $UserID is a member of any of them.  It also seems fairly clear that I will need to use both ExchangeOnline and AzureAD modules, which is okay.

I'll update this as I go along!  Thanks!

Comment: Get-Recipient -Filter "Members -eq 'CN=Test User,OU=TestDomain.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=NAMPR10C042,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM'"

Basically does the same thing as the large code block but as one liner

Comment: Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox also pulls Rooms and equipment, however, Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User Test@domain.com does not provide any results.

Comment: Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox")'| Select Identity,GrantSendOnBehalfTo | Export-Csv -Path "c:\users2\RoomsEquipment.csv" -NoTypeInformation     This command will show all users with GrantSendOnBehalfTo, however it throws all of the names into one cell in excel, trying to figure out how to split that up (not really needed but want to learn).  Now I will try to output only the Identity that the $UserID belongs to

Answer (score 0):

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$FName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter users first name:","Users first name")
$LName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Users last name","Users last name")
$FullName = ($FName + " " + $LName)

Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox")'| Select Identity,GrantSendOnBehalfTo | ? GrantSendOnBehalfTo -Like *$FullName* | Export-Csv -Path "c:\users2\RoomsEquipment.csv" 

Pause

#Import-Csv -Path "c:\users2\RoomsEquipment.csv" | ? GrantSendOnBehalfTo -Like *$FullName*

Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

Reagrding the Rooms and Equipment searching, this outputs a CSV fairly how I want it to work.  Lets say in the script above I select User2 as the requested user, the output is the screenshot below.

```
https://imgur.com/NBI5DyQ
```

Next is to try and tie it all together as one results... if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I work a bit slower on PS since I'm fairly new, however I'd hope that someone could correct my updates or educate me best practices.  Currently Im learning that you cannot export two variables into one CSV without some special magic it would seem.  Currently trying to use this which results in just exporting the last sections of the script, room membership.  Research continues!

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')


$FName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter users first name:","Users first name")
$LName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Users last name","Users last name")
$Email = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Users email address","Users email address")

$UserID = $Email
$FullName = ($FName + " " + $LName)
$CSVFile = "C:\Users2\GroupMemberships.csv"

Import-Module AzureAD
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

Connect-ExchangeOnline
Connect-AzureAD

#Get the User
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserID
 
#Get User's Group Memberships
$AzureMemberships = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $User.ObjectId | Where-object { $_.ObjectType -eq "Group" }
 
#Export group memberships to a CSV
$AzureMemberships | Select DisplayName, Mail, ObjectId | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation

#Gets User room attributes
$ExchangeMemberships = Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox")'

#Export room memberships to a CSV
$ExchangeMemberships | Select Identity,GrantSendOnBehalfTo | ? GrantSendOnBehalfTo -Like *$FullName* | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation

Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false
Disconnect-AzureAD -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')


$FName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter users first name:","Users first name")
$LName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Users last name","Users last name")
$Email = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Users email address","Users email address")

$UserID = $Email
$FullName = ($FName + " " + $LName)
$CSVFile = "C:\Users2\GroupMemberships.csv"

Import-Module AzureAD
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

Connect-ExchangeOnline
Connect-AzureAD

#Get the User
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserID
 
#Get User's Group Memberships
$AzureMemberships = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $User.ObjectId | Where-object { $_.ObjectType -eq "Group" }
 
#Export group memberships to a CSV
#$AzureMemberships | Select DisplayName, Mail, ObjectId #| Export-Csv -LiteralPath $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation

#Gets User room attributes
$ExchangeMemberships = Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox")' 

#Export room memberships to a CSV
#$ExchangeMemberships | Select Identity,GrantSendOnBehalfTo | ? GrantSendOnBehalfTo -Like *$FullName* 

$results = New-Object psobject
$results | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name DisplayName -Value $AzureMemberships.DisplayName
$results | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Mail -Value $AzureMemberships.Mail
$results | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name ObjectId -Value $AzureMemberships.ObjectId
$results | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Identity -Value $ExchangeMemberships.Identity
$results | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name GrantSendOnBehalfTo -Value $ExchangeMemberships.GrantSendOnBehalfTo | ? GrantSendOnBehalfTo -Like *$FullName* 

$results | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation

Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

This results in a CSV file containing wonderful System.Object[] entries.

[image]

hmmm

Answer (score 0):

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
$FName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter users first name:","Users first name")
$LName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Users last name","Users last name")
$Email = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Users email address","Users email address")

$UserID = $Email
$FullName = ($FName + " " + $LName)
$AzureCSV = "C:\Users2\Azure.csv"
$ExchangeCSV = "C:\Users2\Exchange.csv"

Import-Module AzureAD
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

Try {
    #Connect to Azure AD
    Connect-AzureAD
 
    #Get the User
    $User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserID
 
    #Get User's Group Memberships
    $AzureMemberships = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $User.ObjectId | Where-object { $_.ObjectType -eq "Group" }
 
    #Export group memberships to a CSV
    $AzureMemberships | Select DisplayName, Mail | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $AzureCSV -NoTypeInformation
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "`tError:" $_.Exception.Message
}



Try {
    #Connect to Exhange Online
    Connect-ExchangeOnline

    #Get Room mailbox permissions
    $ExchangeMemberships = Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox")'

    #Export room memberships to a CSV
    $ExchangeMemberships | Select Identity,GrantSendOnBehalfTo | ? GrantSendOnBehalfTo -Like *$FullName* | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $ExchangeCSV -NoTypeInformation
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "`tError:" $_.Exception.Message
}

Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false


$CSV1 = Import-Csv "C:\Users2\Azure.csv"
$CSV2 = Import-Csv "C:\Users2\Exchange.csv"

#Import the CSVs
## GC = Get-Content
$csv1 = @(gc "C:\Users2\Azure.csv")
$csv2 = @(gc "C:\Users2\Exchange.csv")
# Create an Empty Array
$csv4 = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $csv1.Count; $i++) {
    $csv4 += $csv1[$i] + ', ' + $csv2[$i]
    }
# Output to file
$csv4 | Out-File "C:\Users2\Results.csv" -encoding default

# Delete the originals
Remove-Item C:\Users2\Azure.csv
Remove-Item C:\Users2\Exchange.csv

Invoke-Item "C:\Users2\Results.csv"
```

This may not be the most efficent way of doing this but it works for me.  I would love to see an experts input on this.  Below is the results.

[image]

What I'd like to figure out next is how to change the Identity header to Room.  I'd also like to try to figure out why they are in quotes.  Maybe even add a space between Mail and Identity header.

Comment: This has answered my problem so far, need to address the questions/issues at bottom of post

Comment: I really struggled with the merging of two CSVs